# Android fragment is not visible after parent onPause and onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments

Consider an Android application which has some basic elements:

There is an activity which holds a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout).

TabLayout's tabs are [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

Let's say I have 4 tabs: A, B, C, D.

The TabLayout is intelligently loads its tabs on demand:
When **Tab A** is displayed, it initiates **Tab B** too, to provide a seamless user experience upon swiping (but C and D is not yet loaded - i.e. their onCreate methods are not yet called).

So, **Tab D** is a Fragment. It also contains another Fragment, which is **Sub D**.

Here is a small log of TabD and TabD_SUB once I select **Tab D** on the TabLayout:

```
TabD_Fragment:    onAttach
TabD_Fragment:    onCreate
TabD_Fragment:    onCreateView
TabD_Fragment:    onResume
TabD_SUBFragment: TabD_SUBFragment Constructor
TabD_SUBFragment: onAttach
TabD_SUBFragment: onCreate
TabD_SUBFragment: onCreateView
TabD_SUBFragment: onStart
TabD_SUBFragment: onResume
// NOW TabD_SUBFragment is visible

// Let's switch to TabC...
TabD_Fragment:    onPause

// ...and go back to TabD
TabD_Fragment:    onResume
// Now TabD_SUBFragment is visible

// Let's switch to TabB...
TabD_Fragment:    onPause
TabD_Fragment:    onStop

// Now switch back to TabD
TabD_Fragment:    onCreateView
TabD_Fragment:    onResume

// And now TabD_SUBFragment is NOT VISIBLE!
```

So obviously, either in TabD's *onStop*, or its *onCreateView*, something happens which prevents my subfragment to be visible.

Here is TabD's *onStop*:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onStop");
    super.onStop();
}
```

Here is TabD's *onCreateView*:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabD, container, false);
}
```

And here is how the subfragment gets constructed in the *onResume* of TabD:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();

    if (null == mSubDFragment) mSubDFragment = new SubDFragment();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.subd_holder, mSubDFragment).commit();
}
```

If I add this code into *onPause* of TabD, it solves this problem, but introduces new ones mainly during orientation changes:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mSubDFragment).commit();
```

### So, my question is, instead of removing the subfragment, how can I make sure that it will be attached and visible when the Tab D is selected?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` to create a child fragment and not `getChildFragmentManager()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a fragment into another fragment, you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`. Have you tried this way in your `TabD` Fragment?